# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 14.1'

Tags: ios, iphone, virtualbox, xcode9.3

I have finish my IOS APP and tested it out on my computer all worked fine and no Problem with it but am facing the below issue when i try to build the application to Archive.

i have tried many option like 
"Automatically manage signing" and "manual"
revoke my certificate recreate and don't no how to build the final APP to upload it to the APP store

i got always the Error msg "Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 14.1'"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfIKZ.png)

Comment: Like the error message says, set the provisioning profile to automatic in the build settings, or use manual signing in the project editor.

Comment: yes it say's on the last error also this one "set the provisioning profile to automatic in the build settings, or use manual signing in the project editor"

Comment: but this was just on the last error the most error is always "Code  signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 14.1"

Comment: i am using macOS 10.13.4 and xcode 9.4